# regexp match pattern and prefix

Tags: php, regex

I need a pattern to match a date and I need the prefix before the date

```
$prefix = '^(.*)';

preg_match("/$prefix(\d+) (may) (2016)/mi", $input, $matches)
```

## input 1 (working)

```
3 may 2016
\\1 
\\2 3
\\3 may
\\4 2016
```

## input 2 (not working)

```
17 may 2016
\\1 1
\\2 7
\\3 may
\\4 2016
```

## input 3 (not working)

```
prefix 17 may 2016
\\1 prefix 1
\\2 7
\\3 may
\\4 2016
```

Comment: the prefix has always a space before the date?

Comment: Use `$prefix = '^(\D*)';`

Comment: the prefix could also contain digits

Comment: So what are the specs? You may use `$prefix = '^(.*?)';`. The greedy matching dot eats up part of your day digits.

Comment: you can use `$prefix = '^(.*\s)?';`

Comment: I advice you to use \s+ or \s? or even \s* for spaces, not all spaces have same admissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I think, it can work:

```
$prefix = '^(.*?)';

preg_match("/$prefix(\d{1,2}) (\w{3,10}) (2016)/", $input, $matches);
```

[Here you can test it.](http://rextester.com/XXMS6621)

Comment: ^(.*?)\s?(\d{1,2})\s+(\w{3,10})\s+(2016) -> it works :d

Comment: why don't use \s ?

Comment: Generally it's possible to use \s. Maybe it's even better to use \s than only space. I used space, because I based from pattern in question.

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
^(.*?)(\d+) (\w+) (\d+)$
```

or if you need specific may and 2016

```
^(.*?)(\d+) (may) (2016)$
```